# Unable to Preserve line breaks and whitespaces while sending Yaml content through Java Client SSH Remote call

Tags: java, linux, kubernetes, ssh, yaml

I'm using Java - SSH Client library and trying to send below content to a remote server.

```
ssh 192.168.8.129 'export KUBECONFIG=/root/.kube/custom/kubeconfig &&
kubectl create -f- << EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  password: $(echo -n 's33msi4' | base64 -w0)
  username: $(echo -n 'jane' | base64 -w0)
EOF'
```

Running this command over the terminal works fine. No issues. However, when I send a same payload within the Java program, I'm losing the format of yml, where spaces and linebreaks are lost.

Below is the encoded string used in java program,

`String content = "apiVersion: v1\nkind: Secret\nmetadata:\n  name: mysecret\ntype: Opaque\ndata:\n  password: $(echo -n 's33msi4' | base64 -w0)\n  username: $(echo -n 'jane' | base64 -w0)";`

However, after running this command from program, the format is completely lost.
Below is the error.

```
STD ERR :: bash: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
error: Unexpected args: [apiVersion: v1 kind: Secret metadata: name: mysecret type: Opaque data: password: czMzbXNpNA== username: amFuZQ== EOF]
```

What is the issue with my formatted input?

Comment: you misuse the double quotes. For example: "s33msi4" should be \"s33msi4\", etc.

Comment: edited the original post. It was tried with single quote.

Comment: You need to show the Java code issuing the command, there seems to be something wrong with the heredoc. Instead of a server-side heredoc, I'd rather send the content from the client via stdin anyway, that would be less prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `cat` your command, for example:

```
$ ssh $server cat << EOF
...command goes here...
EOF
```

*Note: It works using quotes as well.*

Comment: From terminal, its works fine even with or without single quotes

Comment: Thank you. I eddited my answer so it can be useful for the community.